# Navigation drawer in android studio action bar over lap my text content

Tags: android, android-fragments

I m very new to android studio,first sorry for my bad English,I m using new version of android studio 1.4 version ,using default navigation drawer  it working fine but action bar overlap my list content any body help me how to resolve this

app_bar_main

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

here i draw a line for identification,when my activity start It will show like this ,action bar over lap my list without scrolling my fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` to your layout.

Comment: where i need to put this ,in my app_ bar or my fragment layout@Gunaseelan

Comment: when i using this tab my navigation drawer icon was missing and again display same@Gunaseelan

Comment: I glad to help you. And sorry for my late reply, I was busy with my work. And it's good, you find the right place :)

Comment: if u dont mine,when i put my scale type i a getting this message help me          <interface decelaration>,<paracelable declaration>,AidTokenType.import or AidTokenType.package expected,got 'centerCrop'@Gunaseelan

Comment: This issue not related to this question. In which class you got this issue? If I am right, create a separate thread for the new question. So you can get lot of helps from other users also.